# Items not showing in ListView React Native

Tags: react-native, listview, react-native-flatlist

None of my items are showing. I logged the output of the item and the value is proper but nothing is showing. I see that there are list rows created but everything is empty.

```js
render() {
    return this.state.foodList.length > 0 ?
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.foodList}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Divider style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }} />}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            //console.log("*******************");
            //console.log(item);
            return (
              <ListItem
                containerStyle={styles.listItem}
                title={item.name}
                subtitle={`Ingredients: ${item.ingredients}     Calories: ${item.calories}`}
                titleStyle={styles.titleStyle}
                subtitleStyle={styles.subtitleStyle}
                leftAvatar={{
                  size: 'large',
                  rounded: false,
                  //source: item.image && { uri: item.image }
                }}
              />
            );
          }
          }
        />
        <Button  
          title="Go to Scan Again"  
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DashBoardScreen')}  
        />
      </SafeAreaView>: 
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.emptyTitle}>No Foods found</Text>
        <Text style={styles.emptySubtitle}>Add a new food by scanning or entering food in previous screen</Text>
      </View>
      
  }
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove ternary operator? That is, just `return <SafeAreaView....` . Also could you post full return statement? It's hard to tell what's going on without syntax highlighting and so little code.

Comment: No does not work if i remove it. Just updated as well

Comment: Ok, then for now remove ternary operator and even `FlatList`. What happens if you just `render() { return <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}} /> }`? Can you confirm that you see blue screen and the problem is in fact in your code posted here? If so, try adding elements one by one to isolate where you have problem exactly. It might be it is rendering, just the list is empty? What is the value of `this.state.foodList` if you console.log it in render method before `return`?

Comment: I commented out everything and tried to render just the aforementioned safeareaview. I did not get a blue background, but there was no error. Also putting a console.log on this.state.foodList I got the right array of objects.

Comment: can you update the question with your `styles`?